# JavaScript global var return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

in my project i have this JavaScript function as shown below;

```
function refTable(clickon) {

    t_threads = document.getElementById("tab_threads");
    //Activate timeline for specific thread on active thread onclick in table
    t_line = document.getElementById("tline");
    t_lineH1 = GetElementInsideContainer("tl_tit", "tl_h4");
    var c_type = clickon;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "trefresh",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            t_threads.innerHTML = "";
            $.each(data, function (index) {
                var row = t_threads.insertRow(0);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                cell1.innerHTML = data[index].OptionID;
                cell2.innerHTML = data[index].OptionKey;
                cell3.innerHTML = data[index].OptionVal;
                cell4.innerHTML = data[index].OptionVal2;
                cell5.innerHTML = data[index].OptionThread;
        });

        var rows = t_threads.rows; // or table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].onclick = (function() { // closure
                var cnt = i; // save the counter to use in the function
                return function() {
                    task_det(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
                    t_line.style.visibility='visible';
                    t_lineH1.innerHTML = "TIMELINE FOR PROC. ID: "+this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                    c_type = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
                    getTline(c_type)
                    //alert("row"+cnt+" data="+this.cells[0].innerHTML);
                }    
        })(i);
    }
    }
  });

  alert(c_type);
  setTimeout(refTable.bind(c_type), 10000);
}
```

the problem is that anytime the global var `c_type` is populated in my jquery function, at the and, where i place alert, the variable result 'undefined'

How can i make `c_type` global and save it's value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `c_type` isn't global, you've defined it *inside* `refTable()`. Move it outside. Closing as a typo. You should also note that using globals isn't a good design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a variable global just declare it outside of a function

```
var c_type = clickon;
```

and other option could be defining it in the global object, which in browser would be the window..

```
window.c_type = clickon;
```

Anyway isn't  a good Practice defining global variables, it might cause so trouble with other third part libraries.

**Note:**
make sure you don't define the same variable, inside a function you want to work with, in that case the function will take the variable defined in the function...

Comment: No var outside the func nor window work for me, i think call another func into jquery one is the problem, any idea?

Comment: make sure you don't define the same variable, inside a function you want to work with, in that case the function will take the variable defined in the function